# consulta sobre pd.merge

Tags: python, pandas, concat

cuento con el siguiente código:

```
    import pandas as pd
    a = [["2021-08-18", "07:01:02"], ["2021-08-18", "13:26:19"]]
    b = [["2021-08-18", "10:16:48"], ["2021-08-18", "15:41:25"]]
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(a)
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(b)
    df1.columns = ['Fecha', 'Hora Entrada']
    df2.columns = ['Fecha', 'Hora Salida']
    df = pd.concat([df1,df2['Hora Salida']], axis=1)
```

Necesito obtener el mismo resultado con pd.merge, ya que no puedo contar con que los índices se corresponderán
Actualmente tengo esta linea:

```
datos = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='Fecha')
```

Con este método se duplica la unión por dato. Existe la forma de lograr lo que necesito con join, merge, o append en pandas?

De antemano gracias por cualquier respuesta

Answer (score 1):

Hay algunos temas en lo que estás haciendo

Las columnas `Fecha` se crean seguramente como `object`:

```
print(df1.Fecha.dtype)
print(df2.Fecha.dtype)
object
object
```

Esto es mala idea para hacer comparaciones o usarlo en un `merge`, te sugiero transformarlo a un `datetime`:

```
df1['Fecha']= pd.to_datetime(df1['Fecha'])
df2['Fecha']= pd.to_datetime(df2['Fecha'])
```

El otro problema es que está equivocada la forma en que haces el merge, siempre partes de un `dataframe`:

```
datos = df1.merge(df2, on='Fecha', how="inner")
```

El otro problema que conspira para que no obtengas los mismos resultados de `concat` es que tienes dos filas con la misma fecha, por lo que en definitiva se produce un `cross join` y en vez de dos filas obtienes 4. Para resolver esto  necesitas agregar un dato más a la clave que haga que cada fila sea única, por ejemplo podrías enumerar cada grupo de fechas que se repitan:

```
df1['n'] = df1.groupby(['Fecha']).cumcount().add(1)
df2['n'] = df2.groupby(['Fecha']).cumcount().add(1)

datos = df1.merge(df2, on=['Fecha', 'n'], how="inner")
```

Estamos asumiendo que el orden de los dos `dataframes` es coincidente, si no fuera así, habría que ordenarlos previamente para evitar que una "entrada" coincida con la salida de otra "entrada".

Comment: muchas gracias don @Patricio Moracho, la verdad pensaba que me faltaba algún argumento, nunca pensé en agregar otra fila. Gracias por este nuevo enfoque y por la claridad de su respuesta :)